# Not able to send json data through api

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, api, curl

I am using an external api where i have been given the following details related to that api

```
API KEY (Mandatory Header) :- apikey : "xxxxx"
Stage Server Base Url :- https://example.com
To add Details API :- POST(/student/{student_id})
```

What I plan to do is:

> I would be collecting data from users through codeigniter form and
>   then will forward the data to the above api and get a response from
>   the api and accordingly if its a success then would perform furthur
>   actions or else need to display error message

However for testing purpose i am using a static array and trying to send it to the api.

What actually is happening is I am getting a blank result and so not sure if it is working or not.

Following is my code

```
<?php
$apiKey = 'xxxx';
$url = 'https://www.example.com';
$data = array("name"=> "ABC","location"=> "loc","class"=> 'tenth',"area"=> "area");

$ch = curl_init( $url );
$payload = json_encode( $data );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
$headers= curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization: ' . $apiKey));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "<pre>$result</pre>";

?>
```

PS:I am new to api and curl so a little explanation along with the solution would be appreciated

Comment: What is the response status code? Are you sure you're meant to send the API key via the `Authorization` header? Usually that particular header includes an authorization scheme like `Basic` or `Bearer`

Comment: if you are new to api use GuzzleHttp. this library will solve most of your problems. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/

Comment: @Phil i am not getting any response,  i am not able figure out where i am wrong

Comment: do a print_r($result );

Comment: @Akin getting plank page

Comment: what php version are you on?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue using `curl` command line?

Comment: @Akin i am using 5.4

Comment: @Phil i am sorry, i am not aware how to do it

Comment: your curl syntax is ok. i just tried it via phpfiddle and i get a response. Although it was with example.com, but are you sure the external api does not have an issue?

Comment: @Akin will check if that is the case

Comment: @user3732711 something like `curl -v -X POST -d '{"name":"ABC","location":"loc","class":"tenth","area":"area"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: xxxx' 'https://www.example.com/'`

Comment: Again, are you **absolutely sure** the header for the API key is `Authorization: xxxx` and not something more like `apiKey: xxxx`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Accept: application/json',                                                                                
    'Authorization:Basic '.$apikey,
    )                                                                       
);                                                                                                                  
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

try to add whether its Basic or Bearer in authorization header. Hope it works for you.

Comment: still getting blank page

Comment: can u check whether apikey u used is correct ?

Comment: yeah d api key is correct

Comment: "Basic" authorization data is typically base64 encoded. I don't think this is correct

Answer (score -1):

you should use like below statement

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
```

Comment: OP is sending JSON, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`